# No click event on anchor link after appended to DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a problem appending a link to the DOM. After the link has been appended it appears no click event fires on the element.

I have put together this jsFiddle to demonstrate: https://jsfiddle.net/7w1djh9s/

The code:

```
$(function() {
    $(".add-question").click(function() {
        var html = "<li><a href=\"#\">Question " + ($("#questions li").length + 1) + "</a></li>"
        $("#questions").append(html);
    });

    $("#questions a").click(function() {
        alert(1);
    });
});
```

If you click the "Question 1" link, the onclick even is fired. If you add a new question, and then click the new link nothing fires.

Why is this?

Comment: Your event handlers are bound only to the starting/current elements; they must exist at the time your code makes the call to .click(). As suggested by Adam below, binding to the document using .on('click'...) is the preferred way of handling this issue.

Comment: Use event delegation: https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use (if `#questions` is appended dynamically which clearly isn't)

```
$(document).on('click', '{target selector}', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault() // depending on tag
   // code
});
```

Or (in your case)

```
$('#questions').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault() // depending on tag
   // code
});
```

This will keep track of `click` events on the `document` and will fire your code when the selector is found in [`event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event).

Answer (score 0):

You should use this:

```
$("#questions").on('click','a',function() {
    alert(1);
});
```

check [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function from jQuery, this will bind event if HTML was changed.